# Pandas interval data (valid from & valid to) to end of month resampling

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, intervals

I have data extracted from a database where the income for a set of users are stored with valid_from & valid_to dates (multiple income per user possible). I would like to make a row-by-row dataset. On each row I would like show the situation at the end of the month grouped per user.

For the moment, I create a new dataframe with all possible end of months on the index. Then I loop over this index and fill the dataframe accordingly (by filtering from the original dataset).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test_dict = {'valid_from': [np.datetime64('2001-01-01'),np.datetime64('2001-01-15'),np.datetime64('2001-06-20')],\
             'valid_to': [np.datetime64('2001-12-31'),np.datetime64('2001-04-15'),np.datetime64('2001-11-10')],\
             'user' : ['a','b','a'],\
             'income': [200,300,400]}
interval_data = pd.DataFrame(test_dict, columns=['valid_from','valid_to','user','income'])
end_of_month = pd.date_range(start = interval_data.valid_from.min(), end=interval_data.valid_to.max(), freq='M')

dfs = []
for x in end_of_month:
    fltr = (x >= interval_data.valid_from) & (x <= interval_data.valid_to)
    df = interval_data.loc[fltr, :].copy()
    df['date'] = x
    dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs)
group = df.loc[:,['date','user','income']].groupby(['date','user']).sum()

print(interval_data)
print(group)
```

However I guess there is a more efficient way of doing the logic above using the various time and date functions present in Pandas.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
interval_data.groupby(level=0,group_keys=False, as_index=False)\
             .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame({'user':x.user.values,'income':x.income.values},
                                           index=pd.date_range(x.valid_from.values[0],
                                                               x.valid_to.values[0],
                                                               freq='M')))\
             .set_index('user',append=True).sort_index().sum(level=[0,1])
```

Output:

```
                 income
           user        
2001-01-31 a        200
           b        300
2001-02-28 a        200
           b        300
2001-03-31 a        200
           b        300
2001-04-30 a        200
2001-05-31 a        200
2001-06-30 a        600
2001-07-31 a        600
2001-08-31 a        600
2001-09-30 a        600
2001-10-31 a        600
2001-11-30 a        200
2001-12-31 a        200
```

Comment: Basically, if I understand correctly, you are looping over every line in the original DataFrame (interval_data) and creating a DataFrame per line in the apply function ? I didn't know that Pandas would automatically merge these newly created DataFrames. The group_keys=False (avoid adding indexes when using apply) was also new to me. Would it be possible to comment in terms of performance or is that too dependent on the original DataFrame ?